# Receive code not working XBee python

Tags: python-2.7, embedded-linux, xbee, zigbee

Configured two xbee pro s2b using X-CTU, one as coordinator and other as router, API=2, baudrate as 9600. The sender code (coordinator) is as below:

```
import time
from xbee import XBee
import serial

PORT = "/dev/ttyUSB0"
BAUDRATE = 9600

#open serial port
sender_port = serial.Serial(PORT, BAUDRATE)
print "serial port object>>>", sender_port

#xbee object API=2
sender = XBee(sender_port,escaped=True)

#address of the remote xbee to which data is to sent
ADDRESS = "\x00\x13\xA2\x00\x40\xD9\x6F\xE5"

#send data using the tx_long_addr
while True:
    try:
        print "sending data..."
        sender.tx_long_addr(frame_id='A', dest_addr=ADDRESS, data="hello")
        time.sleep(1)

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        break


sender.halt()
sender_port.close()
```

below is the receiver code (router)

```
import time
from xbee import XBee
import serial

PORT = "/dev/ttyUSB1"
BAUDRATE = 9600

def byte2hex(byteStr):
     return ''.join(["%02X" % ord(x) for x in byteStr]).strip()

def decodereceivedFrame(data):
     source_address = byte2hex(data['source_addr'])
     xbee_id = data['id']
     rf_data = data['rf_data']
     options = byte2hex(data['options'])
     return [source_address, xbee_id, rf_data, options]

#open serial port at receiving end
remote = serial.Serial(PORT, BAUDRATE)

#xbee object API=2
remote_xbee = XBee(remote, escaped=True)

while True:
    try:
       print "yes i m here"
       data = remote_xbee.wait_read_frame()
       print "data >>>", data
       decoderdata = decodereceivedFrame(data)
       print "data received<<<<", decoderdata

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
       break

remote_xbee.halt()
remote.close()
```

But on executing the receiver code, nothing happens, it does not print the received message. On X-CTU frames are being transmitted and received without any errors, am i doing something wrong in the code. Please guide .
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue, my fault----

1. sender = ZigBee(sender_port, escaped=True)
2. sender.send('tx', frame_id='A', dest_addr="\x5E\x71", dest_addr_long="\x00\x13\xA2\x00\x40\xD9\x6F\xE5", data="Hello")

Works now ..!!! :)